# Linked list gives segv only occasionally

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I need to implement a linked list, which stores the file names and info as each node.
I decided to fill the node as:

```
struct node
{
    struct stat st;
    char filename[FILENAME_MAX];
    struct node *next;
};
```

I'd like my program to make a linked list out of the file names in any given directory.
I've made a couple of functions to do exactly this.

(xmalloc is simply a wrapper for malloc that exits the program if malloc returns null for some reason)
Add a node to an existing list:

```
struct node *
add_list(struct node **head, struct node n)
{
    struct node *new = xmalloc(sizeof(struct node));
    memcpy(new, &n, sizeof(struct node));
    new->next = NULL;

    new->next = *head;
    *head = new;
    return new;
}
```

Filling a list with files from a given directory:

```
int
fill_list(struct node **head, const char *dirname)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *de;

    if ((dir = opendir(dirname)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("(fill_list) opendir");
        free_list(head);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (de = readdir(dir))
    {
        // Don't add entries for parent dir and current fir
        if (!strcmp(de->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(de->d_name, ".."))
            continue;

        struct node new_node;
        new_node.next = NULL;
        strncpy((new_node.filename), (de->d_name), FILENAME_MAX);
        stat(de->d_name, &(new_node.st));

        add_list(head, new_node);
    }
}
```

Free an existing list:

```
free_list(struct node** head)
{
 
    struct node* current = *head;
    struct node* next = NULL;
 
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        printf("free: %p\n", current);
        current = next;
    }
 
    *head = NULL;
}
```

And finally, print the contents of a list:

```
int
print_list(struct node *head)
{
    while (head->next)
    {
        printf("%s: %ld\n", head->filename, head->st.st_size);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

My main function is

```
int main(void)
{
    struct node *head;
    fill_list(&head, ".");

    print_list(head);
    free_list(&head);
}
```

For some reason, when I run this code, I get a segmentation fault sometimes, not always.
My directory contains
`a.out  list.h  llist.c  log_synfiles.log  syncfiles  syncfiles.c  test.c`
And the times when it runs properly, there's a memory leak.
Why's this happening?

Comment: Why do you use xmalloc and not malloc? You are not checking what xmalloc returns. is it null?

Comment: @AbelTom xmalloc can't return null, its just a wrapper for malloc than exits the program if malloc for some reason returns null

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason, when I run this code, I get a segmentation fault sometimes, not always.

Building your program with Memory Sanitizer and running it yields:

```
==11652==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
    #0 0x49a500 in print_list /tmp/t.c:74:5
    #1 0x49a704 in main /tmp/t.c:86:5
    #2 0x7f8815606e49 in __libc_start_main csu/../csu/libc-start.c:314:16
    #3 0x41f269 in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x41f269)
```

where line 74 is:

```
    72  print_list(struct node *head)
    73  {
    74      while (head->next)
    75      {
    76          printf("%s: %ld\n", head->filename, head->st.st_size);
    77          head = head->next;
    78      }
    79  }
```

This is happening because you "chain on" to `head` defined in `main`, but `head` itself is never initialized. Fix:

```
    81  int main(void)
    82  {
    83      struct node *head = NULL;  // <<<--- initialize it.
    84      fill_list(&head, ".");
```

> And the times when it runs properly, there's a memory leak.

Of course there is:

```
    34      while (current->next != NULL)
    35      {
    36          next = current->next;
    37          printf("free: %p\n", current);
--->>>          free(current);   // Did you intend to free memory here?
    38          current = next;
    39      }
--->>>      free(current);  // Also need to free the last node.
    40
    41      *head = NULL;
    42  }
```

Also you must call `closedir()` to free the `DIR` allocated by `opendir()`.